# Issue with WooCommerce Product Custom Field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the value of a custom field so I can compare it to the amount in stock, and display a message depending on the returned value.

I keep being met with `boolean false` - `string length 0` or `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() on boolean`

```
// check out of stock using 'custom_field' value
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight', 10,3);
    function woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight($variation_id, $variations, $product_id) {

    $grams = get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', true );

    // get product id
    if (isset($_REQUEST["add-to-cart"])) {
        $productid = (int)$_REQUEST["add-to-cart"];
    } else {
        $productid = null;
    }

    // get quantity
    if (isset($_REQUEST["quantity"])) {
        $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST["quantity"];
    } else {
        $quantity = 1;
    }

// get weight of selected variation
    if (isset($_REQUEST["custom_field"])) {
        $weight = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $_REQUEST["custom_field"]);
    } else {
        $weight = null;
    }

    // comparing stock
    if($productid && $weight)
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($productid);
        $productstock = (int)$product->get_stock_quantity();

        if(($weight * $quantity) > $productstock)
        {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You cannot add that amount of "%1$s" to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', $product->get_title(), $productstock ), 'error' );
            return;
        }
    }
    var_dump($grams);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned before, the use of `$_REQUEST` is not necessary.

In the code below, I set `$weight = 40`; for testing purposes. Assuming your `get_post_meta` is correct? and a numerical value?

```php
function validate_attribute_weight( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Get custom field
    $weight = get_post_meta( $variation_id, 'custom_field', true );

    // FOR TESTING PURPOSES, DELETE AFTERWORDS!!!
    $weight = 40;
    // FOR TESTING PURPOSES, DELETE AFTERWORDS!!!

    if ( ! empty( $weight ) ) {
        // Get product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // Get current product stock
        $product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        // ( Weight * quantity ) > product stock
        if( ( ( $weight * $quantity ) > $product_stock ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You cannot add that amount of %1$s to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', $product->get_name(), $product_stock ), 'error' );
            $passed = false;
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_attribute_weight', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: OK... I love you. What the heck did you do that made that work? I realize that ``$_REQUEST`` was unnecessary, but I didn't pay it much mind in the meantime because I was unable to get any values from my ``var_dump`` 

What made these values get pulled? I notice the ``$variation_id = null, $variations = null`` additional arguments in the function - can you explain this?

Why was I unable to see these values in a ``var_dump`` before with exactly the same ``get_post_meta`` request?

Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: first of all you have the order of the parameters, you use $variation_id, $variations, $product_id. This while the first parameter is $passed (see my code). $passed = true. 
So you use 'true' as the variation id. In your code you also use $grams & $weight interchangeably, while this is the same variable In short, a combination of incorrect use, which means that you run into errors.

Comment: If only you knew how many bruises I have on my forehead for this, but I have learned a lot in the process. This code functions perfectly. Much appreciated!